# Replacing a sub-array in C++

Tags: c++

I've got a `uchar` (byte) array called "A" (a long one - it represents an image).
What I need is to replace the sub-array from position i to position j with "B" array.
No need to search "A" for anything, the indices are known.

I can do it byte by byte, of course, but this needs to work in real time, so I'm looking for a library function that does this well.

Comment: Are you aware of `memcpy`?

Comment: There's also `std::copy` in the standard library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This library function is called `memcpy` and defined in header `<cstring>`

For example

```
#include <cstring>

//...

std::memcpy( A + i, B, j - i + 1 );
```

provided that the symbol in position j shall be copied. Otherwise the third argument will be j - i

Comment: @Yonadav Schleifer No problem. As it is said in Russian one head is good but two heads are better.:)

Answer (score 7):

I would do this:

```
std::copy(B, B + i - j, A + i);
```

This will replace in A + i position, contents of B. Actually, the implementation will amount to a memcpy, just as Vlad did. I recommend using std::copy, it is a standard algorithm that, once you learn its interface, is useful for much more than plain old data types and a decent implementation will be optimal or nearly optimal even in the case of plain old data.